# login with flask - unable to obtain data from Postgres using SELECT after an INSERT

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, psycopg2

So I am trying to make an authentication system using OAuth, Flask and Postgres. I'm not too sure what is going on with my code. I created a class for the database which would house the connection and create cursors whenever a query is made. I also made a class for the user which would send queries to be executed on the database class.

This is what I am trying to do:

- In the main application, we check if the user has been authenticated
- If not, we go through the process of OAuth/OpenConnect
- Once we get the credentials from the Google API, we check the database if there was anything stored with the id from the response with a method from the user class
- If no id was found, we insert into the database using the user class method to make a query
- Then we use flask-login methods, `@login_manager.user_loader` which then calls the user class method to SELECT from the database
- Where my issue is, it appears that I am unable to retrieve the data

Some resources I have tried to follow to fix this problem:

- [should I reuse the cursor in the python MySQLdb module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099902/should-i-reuse-the-cursor-in-the-python-mysqldb-module)
- [Executing different queries using mysql-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097844/executing-different-queries-using-mysql-python/8097928)
- [PostgreSQL/performance one general cursor or create for every query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773372/postgresql-performance-one-general-cursor-or-create-for-every-query)

Not sure what's wrong.. I have psql open on my terminal and when I run the SELECT, I do in fact see the entry with the correct id.. But my application isn't able to fetch the data.

**db.py**

```
import psycopg2 
from psycopg2 import Error

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db, user, password, port, host):
        self.db = db
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.port = port 
        self.host = host

    def connect(self):
        self.connection = psycopg2.connect(
            database=self.db,
            user=self.user,
            password=self.password,
            port=self.port,
            host=self.host
        )

    def executeQuery(self, query, values=None):
        print('query:', query)
        print('values:', values)
        cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, values)
        self.connection.commit()
        cursor.close()

    def close(self):
        self.connection.close()
```

**user.py**

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from db import db

class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, id, name, email, profile_pic):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.profile_pic = profile_pic
    
    @staticmethod
    def get(user_id):
        user = db.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=%s;', (user_id,))
        print('user:', user)
        if not user:
            return None
        current_user = user.fetchone()
        user = User(
            id = current_user[0],
            name = current_user[1],
            email = current_user[2],
            profile_pic = current_user[3]
        )
        return user

    @staticmethod
    def create(id, name, email, profile_pic):
        db.executeQuery(
            'INSERT INTO users (id, name, email, profile_pic) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s);', (id, name, email, profile_pic,)
        )
```

Documentation for Psycopg2:
https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html

Maybe, my design for the database and user class is completely off. Feel free to let me know if I need to provide more information!

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake is here

```
user = db.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=%s;', (user_id,))
```

It should be

```
user = db.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=(%s);' , (user_id))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, it is in the documentation for how to write queries: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html

Comment: that's mean the issue still on ?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. :( The syntax is weird.. But I don't think that was the issue. Thanks though!

Comment: i edited the answer check it again please and tell me

Comment: I've used this: 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=%s;' on psql running on a separate terminal and I am able to fetch the results. My application however is not. I don't think that is a valid query string

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my previous database class used `executeQuery` for all types of queries. But I believe that may be the reason why I am getting wrong results. I found this link: [Python MySQLdb - Connection in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076220/python-mysqldb-connection-in-a-class). I noticed that one person implemented separate methods for executing and fetching queries, so I thought I would give that a try and to my surprise, it worked! So I have refactored my code to look like this:

```
def fetch(self, query, values=None):
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query, values)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    return result

def execute(self, query, values=None):
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query, values)
    self.connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
```